# date conversion with format

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a datetime column and I want to convert date using

```
format(GETDATE(),'yyyy/MM/dd','fa')
```

but it says format is not recognized as built-in function name

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what you are trying to do.

Comment: Please also let us know what database engine and version you are using (I'm assuming SQL Server)

Comment: Please specify which database you are using and what's the version. It seems sql-server in which this should work.

Comment: `Format` was added in SQL Server 2012. Are you running a more _mature_ (and less supported) version? (`select @@Version;`)

Comment: I can't repro this. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=04f9724fa661e82f5a423dad5ba71495)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably using a SQL Server 2005-2008 or you have SQL Server 2012 and your database in set to 2005-2008 compatibility level. You can change the compatibility level if you are on SQL 2012 and you know it's safe to do so, otherwise you will need to use `CONVERT` instead.

```
CONVERT(varchar, GETDATE(), 111)
```

[CAST and CONVERT (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)